# I have a long table in a div, when I scroll the table, I want to see it moves inertially HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a long table(the width is very large), when I scroll that table from left to right, I want it moves inertially. The current version of mine is just when I use my finger to scroll it, it moves but when I hold up my finger it stopped. What should I do? Here is a part of my HTML code for that table inside the div.

```
           <div class="welcomeProgram">
                <p class=programTitle>Project</p>
                <div class="outer">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td><a href="#"><img src="img/ast_youxue.png"/></a><p>Project1</p></td>
                                <td><a href="#"><img src="img/canada_youxue2.png"/></a><p>project2</p></td>
                                <td><a href="#"><img src="img/usa_youxue2.png"/></a><p>project3</p></td>
                                <td><a href="#"><img src="img/uk_youxue2.png"/></a><p>project4</p></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And there is my css code:

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    *margin-left: -100px;/*ie7*/
}
td, th {
    vertical-align: top;
    padding:2px;
    width:330px;
}

.outer {
    position:relative;
    margin-top: 2%;
}
.inner {
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:visible;
    width:97%;
    margin-left:0%;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
.inner img{
    width: 100%;
}
.inner p{
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 4%;
    margin-left: 1%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your asking. "inertially" isn't a word in the dictionary. Inertia is, but it's the absence of motion AKA a body that stays at rest. See: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/inertia

It sounds like the table is already doing what it needs to do, when the user's cursor or finger releases the table... it stops.

If you want it to keep moving, you'd need to use a library like jQuery to animate it. HTML + CSS won't do that by themselves. You could start the scroll onKeyDown & then onMouseMove. It'd be similar to programming a drag & drop operation, using jQuery. Once you've setup 2 flags to track the onKeyDown & onMouseMove, where both flags are set to true, then you could use the onKeyUp event to run the animation. You could use .scrollLeft() to allow it to continue to keep moving. See: https://api.jquery.com/scrollleft/

Would you please clarify, what you're looking for the table to do?

Edit: I tried to add this to the comments, but it wouldn't fit into it.
See if this helps...

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .wrap {
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    table {
      width: 10000px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrap"></div>
</body>
<footer>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      // Generate Table
      var table = '<table border="1"><tr>';
      for (var i=0; i<1000; i++) {
        table += '<td>Hi</td>';
      }
      table += '</tr></table>';
      $('.wrap').html(table);

      // Run Animation
      $('.wrap').on('scroll', function(){
          $(this).animate({
            scrollLeft: "+=50"
          }, 800);
      });
    });
  </script>
</footer>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you give me an example, I try to use scrollleft but I failed. "inertially" is when a user release his finger, the table should scroll and then stop slowly.

Comment: I find a problem that when I scroll it, it continue scrolling, how to let that stop?

Comment: With an decrementing variable. Try playing with the demo to set var pixels = 50.  Then use pixels--, so that each time that the animation runs... it decrements pixels by -1. I'd add that as a function into the 3rd parameter of the animation function. With `scrollLeft: "+=" + pixels` in the animation JSON code, the scroll will eventually slow down to a stop. So it should move 50px, then 49px, then 48px, ... 2px, 1px, 0px.

Comment: If you also add an if statement around the animation code, you can have it only start the animation when an onMouseUp flag has been set to true. You'll also have to add an onMouseUp event to track that boolean.

Comment: However, I have some more question? How to judge is the user scroll from left to right or from right to left? because, it only works with the situation for scroll from left to right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106053/discussion-between-hanslen-chen-and-clomp).

Comment: Cool! I can't chat tonight. Perhaps tomorrow. However, if you track the current $(this).scrollLeft value & the last $(this).scrollLeft value, you can subtract the two to get the delta change. The + or - pixel direction will tell you which way that the user is scrolling. Then you can use it as a +pixel or -pixel value for scrolling either direction.